# android facebook login intergration to get user detail

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Now i am  working on Facebook login integration in my app.i cant able to get the email id,birth-date and profile pic.i already seen some posts regrading this question they are outdated now.it's not working properly.what i am trying is

```
  fb_login.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", 
 "user_birthday,user_gender"));
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    fb_login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new 
   FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code
                            getDate(object);
                            Log.d("REsponse",response.toString());
                            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Form.class);
                            startActivity(in);
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
}
private void getDate(JSONObject object){
    try {
        URL profile_pic = new 
  URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+object.getString("id")+"/picture?width = 
 250&height=250");
        Picasso.with(this).load(profile_pic.toString()).into(image);
        id.setText(object.getString("id"));
        name.setText(object.getString("name"));
        email.setText(object.getString("email"));
        gende.setText(object.getString("gender"));
        birthday.setText(object.getString("birthday"));

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

i get only the name and faceebook id.i need your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

import com.facebook.Profile;

From Profile class you will get Image

```
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
```

use the below method you will get image uri, specify width and height.

profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString()